# The death of Earthworm

Tags: entomology

In rainy season when children sprinkle salt on earthworm ,it dies.But salt is not dangerous.We use it daily.Then why earthworm dies?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: "salt is not dangerous" - Citation needed.

Comment: We use salt daily and ofcourse children don't take it off from mines just to sprinkle it on earthworms.I'm talking of table salt.Any more citation?

Comment: Ever heard of what happens when you drink salt water? Alle Dinge sind Gift, und nichts ist ohne Gift, allein die Dosis macht dass ein Ding kein Gift ist: the dose makes the poison.

Comment: Re "salt is not dangerous", you might consider why low-salt diets are recommented for people with high blood pressure or some kinds of heart disease, or why rubbing salt into wounds has become a common saying.

Comment: Well it is dangerous but it is not poisonous.

Comment: @Sara Asfar: Salt certainly is poisonous, it's just that it takes a fairly large amount to kill you.  Per Google, the LD50 of sodium chloride is about 3000 mg/kg, so eating about half a pound would likely be fatal.  Note that it's fairly common for things to be harmless or even necessary for health in small quantities, but harmful or fatal in larger amounts.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It's because on the earth worm skin's special mucous. Acording to this article: [Why do earthworms die when salt is sprinkled on them?](http://megaanswers.com/why-do-earthworms-die-when-salt-is-sprinkled-on-them/) the mucous makes moist to the worm's skin, which is  vital for their survival. Moreover, the worms don't have a respiratory organs, like lungs, gills, etc. This means that Carbon Dioxide and other characterized as "dump" gases can not be exchanged with the Oxygen. But worms breath through their skin, with the help of these special mucous that are developed on its skin. If their skin dries out the result will be death, because the gas exchange will not last without the mucous help. Similarly, the circulatory system won't function, because its main role is to trade gasses with the cells via red blood cells.

**What about salinity?**

Salinity is a very important factor for the earthworms health, because high salinity destroy their valunable and sensitive skin and kills the mucous that in fact help the worm to "breathe". Low salt concentrations are very beneficial for the worm, because not only their mortarity level is increaced, there are size changes to the worm's body (noticeable bigger size).

Here are and some photos of a worm that its enviroment has low salinity and high salinity:

**High salinity:**

[image]

**Low-to-medium salinity**

[image]

Source: [**Why do earthworms die when salt is sprinkled on them?**](http://megaanswers.com/why-do-earthworms-die-when-salt-is-sprinkled-on-them/).

Comment: When quoting an article, the quotes should be clearly marked, otherwise it's considered a form of plagiarism.

Comment: Either it is plagiarism or not but it really gave me answer to my question.Why the people like you seem to proof read other's post just for criticizing them or down vote them@anongoodnurse

Comment: @SaraAsfar plagiarism is quite a serious problem. It's not just about getting *your* answer, the answerer should write a proper answer for *this whole community*, acknowledging all its conventions and restrictions.

Comment: @OP - plagiarism is considered serious malpractice. Please convert your answer into your own words, or explicitly mention where the citations were obtained from at the appropriate places in your answer.

Comment: @AliceD Okay I am making it community wiki.

Comment: @The_Mad_Fish and why would that make things better?

Comment: @AliceD Please check my new anwer that it is based on the article and doesn't show any plagiarism. Thanks.

Comment: Also, edits are welcome :)